# Recommended rails deployment & file structure on an existing Apache Server

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, deployment, apache2

I am developing an application with **Ruby on Rails** (will be more to come) and it has got to the stage where I would like to remotely host a development version, followed by a production one. I have done lots of rails development but I am reviewing my current setup and would like to make sure I do things the industry recommended way form now on.

I already have a dedicated server which is running **parallels plesk** and has several domains on it. I have currently had some success by creating a new user "passenger" to run the rails app and deploying via that user to an apps directory under

```
/var/www/vhosts/myrailsapp.com/subdomains/dev/
```

which is the parallels-format for site directories, deploying using **capistrano** and running the **passenger** module for **apache**. I have basically been putting my rails files where I would put them if it were a plain php site or similar and I was wondering if this was the way things are usually done?

I also found some information online which points at putting my rails apps under

/var/apps/

or similar, but then it would conflict with the parallels plesk way of doing things which could potentially cause issues, or could it?

I have already looked at solutions like **Heroku** and they won't quite work as I need to run other programs alongside my rails app on the same server to handle some real time server to server file syncing of files uploaded using the app. Added to this I need to ideally be able to host normal PHP applications alongside my RoR ones to make best use of the server.

How should I ideally go about implementing this sort of setup for secure hosting and deployment? If needs be (i.e my current setup is far less than ideal) you could assume I am starting from a vanilla ubuntu server install which I would be open to if it produced a nicer system to manage.

I figured many people would have had similar situations and so any advice from any of you veteran Rails/PHP developers or server admins would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it's a bad idea to put your Rails project files anywhere in your public html space because you don' want anybody to be able to put something like http://yoursite.com/config/database.yml and access sensitive information. Even if that's not possible under normal situations, it could still happen if you have problems with Passenger starting up correctly or something similar.

So I would recommend putting your Rails apps in `/var/apps` or `/srv/apps` (as we've done) and setup the Apache config to point your domain or subdomain to that directory.

If you want to have your app accessible by a subdirectory on an existing domain it takes some additional setup but that can also be done.

Comment: Would you run each app under a different user with access to each app in /var/apps/ or have one "passenger" user with permissions for the /var/apps/ folder?

Comment: It's best to run each app as a different user for security reasons.

Comment: How does that work alongside passenger? With multiple apps do I have one instance of passenger with apache2 and just have one user per app directory? Also, just thinking ahead, production vs development, thinking /srv/apps/myapp/production and /srv/apps/myapp/development. would you suggest I have different users for them too?

Comment: Yes, you can run one instance of Passenger which will run multiple processes for your apps. You can use [user switching](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#user_switching) to run each app as a different user.

It's probably not necessary to your development and production apps as different users.